# iOS Objec-C error for object pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, autorelease

I'm getting the following error in xcode.

**error for object 0x4e18d00: pointer being freed was not allocated ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug**

I've setup NSZombieEnabled in the target so I can view the call. It is

**-[___NSArrayI release]**

It looks like i've released some array somewhere else in my code and then the auto release pool is trying to release it also when it is already dealloc'd.

How can I find out where? Any idea?

FYI, I'm creating all my arrays using the `arrayWithCapacity` method or something similar, never use `alloc` or `init` methods. I don't see, anywhere where I am releasing those same arrays. (maybe i'm blind!!)

Also, the control flow is as follows: I click an `UIButton`, fire the function attached to onclick. This will go to various logic layers and then get an `NSArray` back. I can then iterate this array in the "onClick button function" and print the contents.
When this "onClick button function" quits I get the above error in the "main" method.

Another note is that in one function I create an NSMutableArray but want to return an `NSArray` so I use `[[mutableArray copy] autorelease]`. This ok, right?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I often have great difficulty in trying to track the cause for errors down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done what it suggests and set a break point on `malloc_error_break` and then run the code in the debugger?

Comment: I was just about to update my question and ask how to go about this in xcode 4. I tried before but couldn't figure it out..

Are there any tutorials for this?

Comment: Sorry, I only know how to do it in Xcode 3.

Comment: Breakpoint tab, + sign at the bottom, Add Symbolic Breakpoint, type in malloc_error_break in symbol then click done.

Comment: i've added the breakpoint (like I tried before) and still nothing. It doesn't even seem to break at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong..

In book class I had chapters declared as an NSAray and in the default constructor I said

```
chapters = [NSArray array];
```

I took that out of the constructor and all is well.
Thanks for your help guys.

P.S. If I forget can somebody please mark this as the accepted answer? Cheers ;)

Answer (score -1):

When your app crashes you can see at which line your app crashed and you can also see sequence of functions called before crash happen. I think this line is causing crash [[mutableArray copy] autorelease]. because you are not retaining it. copy returns an autoreleased object. You can see in documentation that what the function is returning. In objective-c normally returns an autoreleased object.

Comment: That is incorrect here is documentation from the NSCopying protocol and remember the sender is you. "The returned object is implicitly retained by the sender, who is responsible for releasing it. The copy returned is immutable if the consideration “immutable vs. mutable” applies to the receiving object; otherwise the exact nature of the copy is determined by the class."

Comment: Remember NARC (new, alloc, retain, copy/mutableCopy) return an owned object.

Comment: Ok, well I figured out the problem.

I have a book object that contains Chapters.. (an NSArray of chapter objects)

I was putting the mutableArray into book.chapters. Commenting that line solved my problem. I've tried to use [mutableArray copy] to put the chapters in there but it still crashes. Any ideas? Thanks.